# Awk search for a specific field in an XML file

Tags: xml, apache, search, awk

I have an awk control file called vsearch.awk on an Ubuntu 14.04 Server, which contains two simple lines of code, as follows:

```
BEGIN { RS="\n\n" ; }
$0 ~ search { print }
```

I am running this file from the command line to search for a particular field in an XML file, like so:

```
awk -f vsearch.awk search=example stuff.xml
```

And it prints out the exact field I need (containing the word "**example**").
However, when I run it against an Apache host .conf file (which also appears to be in an XML format), awk just spits out the entire file as a result. 
I used both gawk and mawk with the same results (Both work on regular XML files, but not on the .conf file.)

Any ideas why?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the lines separators are not the same in the 1st XML and the .conf file.

Comment: Try and see if the file contains something weird or it is from a DOS system. You can `cat -vet` it and check weird characters.

Comment: @fedorqui cat -vet displays $ special character at the end of each line. However (strangely) the $ also appears 2 spaces in on the lines separating each paragraph. Is that standard behavior?

Comment: @fedorqui - I edited the .conf file to remove those extra spaces in the paragraph-separating lines, and awk runs the search just fine now! Thanks for your help! PS. You can add your suggestion as an official answer, so I can accept it and up-vote it.

Comment: Nice to read it is solved, @Cain ! Just posted an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some lines with trailing spaces in between those paragraphs. Thus, `awk` considered two different paragraphs as the same, since they were not separated by the set `RS=\n\n` but, instead, by something like `\n  \n`.

Note I suggested to say `cat -vet <file>` because this way you can see all the trailing spaces, tabs and end of line.

From `man cat`:

```
   -e     equivalent to -vE

   -E, --show-ends
          display $ at end of each line

   -t     equivalent to -vT

   -T, --show-tabs
          display TAB characters as ^I

   -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

#### Test

Let's prepare a two paragraphs file but with trailing spaces instead of empty lines in between:

```
$ cat -vet a
hello$
$                  # two trailing spaces
how are you$
```

It just "sees" one paragraph:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\n" ; } {print NF}' a
4
```

Now if we remove those trailing spaces:

```
$ cat -vet a
hello$
$                    # no trailing spaces
how are you$
```

It "sees" two paragraphs:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS="\n\n" ; } {print NF}' a
1
3
```

With `$` you see the end of line, and since you see `$` it means there are two spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation, and for the effort, @fedorqui. This is great!